# GDI+ GraphicsPath is displayed differently on screen and on paper

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I have the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawPath(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += Pd_PrintPage;
        pd.Print();
    }

    private void Pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = false;
        DrawPath(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void DrawPath(Graphics g)
    {
        g.MultiplyTransform(new Matrix(10, 0, 0, -10, 30, 80));

        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.StartFigure();
        path.AddLine(0, 0, -0.96f, 0.96f);
        path.AddLine(-0.96f, 0.96f, -0.96f, 3.12f);
        path.AddLine(-0.96f, 3.12f, 0, 4.08f);
        path.AddLine(0, 4.08f, 2.16f, 4.08f);
        path.AddLine(2.16f, 4.08f, 3.12f, 3.12f);
        path.AddLine(3.12f, 3.12f, 3.12f, 0.96f);
        path.AddLine(3.12f, 0.96f, 2.16f, 0);
        path.CloseFigure();

        path.StartFigure();
        path.AddLine(11.52f, 0f, 12.48f, -0.96f);
        path.AddLine(12.48f, -0.96f, 14.64f, -0.96f);
        path.AddLine(14.64f, -0.96f, 15.6f, 0);
        path.AddLine(15.6f, 0, 15.6f, 2.16f);
        path.AddLine(15.6f, 2.16f, 14.64f, 3.12f);
        path.AddLine(14.64f, 3.12f, 11.52f, 3.12f);
        path.AddLine(11.52f, 3.12f, 11.52f, 5.04f);
        path.AddLine(11.52f, 5.04f, 15.6f, 5.04f);

        path.StartFigure();
        path.AddLine(20, 5, 30, 2);
        path.AddLine(30, 2, 20, -1);

        g.DrawPath(Pens.Black, path);

        path.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When displayed on screen the path looks like this (correct output):

[image: Path displayed on screen]

When printed (paper or PDF, does not matter) the path looks like this (incorrect output):

[image: Path printed on PDF]

What can be done to get the path printed correctly?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes, only the first figure must be closed, the other must remain open. But it seems that the print system also closes the second figure, I do not know why

Comment: It appears to be affected by the previous CloseFigure() call.  Workaround is to create a new GraphicsPath.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up replacing the CloseFigure with an AddLine(currentPosition, startPosition). Visually it looks the same in my actual application. Creating 2 paths would have required to many changes in the application.